# Hyperlink in a JLabel

Tags: java

I have a `JLabel` in my *about us* form which I'd like to be a hyperlink to `www.samteksystems.com`, which means that whenever I click on that `JLabel` it should go to `www.samteksystems.com`. Please help me.

Comment: You may wish to look over this page as well:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Answer (score 4):

use HTML

```
 String str = "<a href=\"www.samteksystems.com\" >samteksystems</a>";
 jLabel.setText(str);
```