# I want To insert hyperlink in JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, hyperlink

I want To insert hyperlink in JPanel (so that on clicking i go to web address)
 Is it possible ? 
If yes, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been using something like this:

```
public class UrlTextPane extends JTextPane {

private final Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(UrlUtil.URL_REGEX);

public UrlTextPane() {
    this.setEditable(false);
    this.addHyperlinkListener(new UrlHyperlinkListener());
    this.setContentType("text/html");
}

private class UrlHyperlinkListener implements HyperlinkListener {
    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(event.getURL().toURI());
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't open URL", e);
            } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't open URL", e);
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
/**
 * Set the text, first translate it into HTML:
 */
public void setText(final String input) {

    final StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    answer.append("<html><body style=\"font-size: 8.5px;font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif\">");

    final String content = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(input);

    int lastIndex = 0;
    final Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(content);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        //Append everything since last update to the url:
        answer.append(content.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start()));
        final String url = content.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).trim();
        if(UrlUtil.isValidURI(url)) {
            answer.append("<a href=\"" + url + "\">"+url+"</a>");
        } else {
             answer.append(url);
        }
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }
    //Append end:
    answer.append(content.substring(lastIndex));
    answer.append("</body></html>");
    super.setText(answer.toString().replace("\n", "<br />"));
}
```

}

Comment: UrlUtil contains an URL regex and a method that tries to parse the URL to a Java URI (which is very strict).

Answer (score 3):

See the [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)
 tutorial.

Comment: @ stacker i want that when i click on hyperlink,i go to the mentioned address.That is not explained there

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function that takes the text, link, and the position you want to display and returns a `JLabel`. When the mouse is over the text, it becomes blue with underline and makes cursor a pointing hand, otherwise it becomes black with no underline and default cursor.

```
    public static JLabel makeHyperLink(final String s, final String link, int x, int y)
{
    final JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
    l.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            l.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            l.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            l.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            l.setText(String.format("<HTML><FONT color = \"#000099\"><U>%s</U></FONT></HTML>", s));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                URI uri = new URI(link);
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    });

    l.setBounds(x, y, s.length()*5, 20);
    l.setToolTipText(String.format("go to %s", link));
    return l;
}
```

If any part of code is not clear, contact me;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible,

Use `HTML`

[Add one JLabel use HTML as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538149/hyperlink-in-a-jlabel) and add it to Panel

Comment: I said , add a label and set its text as HTML and then add it to panel

Comment: @  Jigar Joshi But i am unable to click it.How do i do this?